# How to upsert in (key,value) sqlite database table?

Tags: sqlite

I have a (key,value) database table in `sqlite`. I want to `update` an existing key with the value in case it already exists. And if the key doesn't exist, `insert` the key and value into the table.

What would be best `sql statement` to do that?

I am creating the table using the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE KeyValueTable ( EntityName TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, EntityValue BLOB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html provides the information about how to do upsert in `sqlite`. Note that this feature was `added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04)`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KeyValueTable VALUES ($key, $value)
```

While `INSERT OR REPLACE` is not, in general, equivalent to an UPSERT, it should work for your situation, and is compatible with older versions of SQLite.